# print to file bash usernames and account status

Tags: bash

I would like to create a script that would loop through /etc/passwd and print all usernames and account status.

```
while read line; do
print username to field1 in user.txt
print status active/disabled in field2 in user.txt
done</etc/passwd
```

Comment: You mean print to a printer or print to stdout?

Answer (score 0):

```
while IFS=: read user status placeholder; do
    [[ $status == x ]] && active=active || active=inactive
    echo "$user $active" >> user.txt
done < /etc/passwd
cat user.txt
```

But if the second column is `x` the user have an encrypted password, that not stands for active or inactive...

See

```
man 5 passwd
```

You should look

```
account expiration date
```

in

```
man 5 shadow
```